# SVD for recommendation engine

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, recommendation-engine, svd

I'm trying to build a toy recommendation engine to wrap my mind around Singular Value Decomposition (SVD). I've read enough content to understand the motivations and intuition behind the actual decomposition of the matrix A (a user *x* movie matrix).

I need to know more about what goes on after that.

```
from numpy.linalg import svd
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([ 
  [0, 0, 0, 4, 5],
  [0, 4, 3, 0, 0],
  ...
])
U, S, V = svd(A)

k = 5 #dimension reduction
A_k = U[:, :k] * np.diag(S[:k]) * V[:k, :]
```

Three Questions:

1. Do the values of matrix `A_k` represent the the predicted/approximate ratings?
2. What role/ what steps does cosine similarity play in the recommendation?
3. And finally I'm using Mean Absolute Error (MAE) to calculate my error. But what I'm values am I comparing? Something like `MAE(A, A_k)` or something else?

Comment: You probably want to ask someplace like http://datascience.stackexchange.com. As it is, this is not a programming question.

Comment: Good point. I'll move the question to there

Comment: here's a link to the question if anybody sees it on here first: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15457/svd-for-recommendation-engine